# How do I search for the content of files in a Perforce depot (P4V)?

Tags: search, perforce, p4v, depot

I am currently using Perforce version 2010.2.
It appears that this version does not have an integrated search functionality that will go through the content of every single file.
My current P4V version only allows me to search for filenames but not for content.

Any input on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the 'p4 grep' command, added in release 2010.1, I believe.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, you can also look at a repository search tool.  I think Black Duck has one that works with Perforce.

Comment: Example: `p4 grep -n -e "my_regex_pattern" //my_depot/.../*.ext`

Comment: Just for convenience: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v18.1/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_grep.html