# Perforce search in depot for files which have some keyword(s) as content

Tags: search, perforce

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519342/how-do-i-search-for-the-content-of-files-in-a-perforce-depot-p4v) but is seemed a commandline option and for some reason p4 grep did not give me results. It gave errors like "must refer to client".

So i am asking, does the P4 visual client(I have version 2012 Sep-21) have any provision to search depot files for certain content entered as keyword(s)?

This is what I did to use p4 grep command:

cd

```
p4 grep -i -n -e dmc ./
```

this gave error:

```
./ - file(s) not in client view.
```

So then tried doing switch command to change to that client/workspace(they are synonyms in Perforce):

p4 client -s MyClientName

It gave error saying:

```
Usage: client -s [ -f ] -t template | -S stream [ clientname ]
```

Then even tried further but could not use the -S -t option.

What is the command to switch a client which would resolve the error message "./ - file(s) not in client view."?

Comment: do you also want to search file content in history? Otherwise a regular Windows search can help you. With the downside that you'll also search non depot files...

Comment: If you paste the exact 'p4 grep' command you entered, and the exact message that you received, you might get help on the 'for some reason' part of your question...

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton Have updated my question to mention what errors i got in p4 grep command. Let me know if u have nay pointers to get p4 grep working.

Comment: Indeed, 'p4 grep' works best with file specifications given in depot syntax, not in client syntax, as you relate in your answer to your own question below. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well finally after lot of trials and errors (There is not much discussion about this online) I got the p4 grep command to work successfully.

cd to your

```
grep -i -n -F -e "class"  //depot/folder1/folder2/code/*
```

The key is using the Perforce folder notation `//depot/...`

You can use any option of the grep command mentioned in its help.
One can even use regular expressions as patterns/keyword.

Well done your's truly.

Answer (score 0):

No, p4v does not have the ability to search the content of files, you will need to use
"p4 grep" to do that.

Comment: Ok. What would be the exact p4 grep command to search it. any pointers to get this working?

Comment: You can search content of files in your Perforce worksapce. See my reply below